# Execute a python file in a bash file and read two text file

Tags: python, bash

I have a python file which works fine. It takes a file and does something on it. So I run it like this:

> ./MyPy.py File.txt

Then with bash script I grep some part of it.

> ./MyPy.py File.txt | grep -vE "^color"

So what I want to do is creating a bash file which asks the user for the path of the File and does ./MyPy.py File.txt | grep -vE "^color" in it and gives the result to out put.

Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: So you want to read the file name at run time into a variable? Have you tried using `read`? Look in the bash manual.

Comment: why not just use `re` and do it all in python?

Comment: Hi guys,
Padraic: Cuz I had to do it in bash.
Tom: Thanks, read worked for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -e -p "Enter the path of the file: " file
./MyPy.py "$file" | grep -vE "^color"
```

> Additional improvement:

If you want to interpret `~` as `/home/user` i.e use `~/Downloads` to point to `/home/user/Downloads`, then:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -e -p "Enter the path of the file: " file
file=${file/#\~/$HOME}
./MyPy.py "$file" | grep -vE "^color"
```

Comment: `eval` can also be used to do a second scan to translate the `~`, but `eval` is evil.